# error while writing to csv file with python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write some output to csv file line by line

Here what I tried:

```
import csv

today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
filter = "eventTimestamp ge {}".format(today)
select = ",".join([
    "eventTimestamp",
    "eventName",
    "operationName",
    "resourceGroupName",
])

activity_logs = client.activity_logs.list(
    filter=filter,
    select=select
)   

with open(r"C:\scripts\logs.csv", 'w', newline='') as f:
    for log in activity_logs:
        result = (" ".join([
            str(log.event_timestamp),
            str(log.resource_group_name),
            log.event_name.localized_value,
            log.operation_name.localized_value
        ]))
        f.writerow(result)
```

Its throwing error:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writerow'
```

How can i fix this error, possibly any other module ?

Comment: use write and add a `\n` instead

Comment: Do you really want to have spaces as separators in your 'CSV' file?

Comment: no its comma as delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
with open(r"C:\scripts\logs.csv", 'w', newline='') as f:
```

is creating just text file handle. You need to create `csv.writer` using `f` and then you might use `writerow`, that is:

```
import csv
...
with open(r"C:\scripts\logs.csv", 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for log in activity_logs:
        result = (str(log.event_timestamp),str(log.resource_group_name),log.event_name.localized_value,log.operation_name.localized_value)
        writer.writerow(result)
```

You might find useful examples of usage in [csv article at PyMOTW-3](https://pymotw.com/3/csv/index.html)

Comment: Hi its works now, but how can i add header into this ? I mean for each delimited text, i need to add customised column names in 1st line

Comment: `headers = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4']` added before for loop, but its not printing as header row

Comment: @asp: add `writer.writerow(('Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4'))` immediately before `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from the line:

`f.writerow(result)`

and it's telling you that the f object does not have a function named writerow.

As Jannes has commented, use the write function instead:

`f.write(result)`

Answer (score 1):

CSV.writer is required when your trying to write into CSV . then the code can be

```
import csv

today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
filter = "eventTimestamp ge {}".format(today)
select = ",".join([
    "eventTimestamp",
    "eventName",
    "operationName",
    "resourceGroupName",
])

activity_logs = client.activity_logs.list(
    filter=filter,
    select=select
)   

with open(r"C:\scripts\logs.csv", 'w', newline='') as file:
    f=csv.writer(file)
    for log in activity_logs:
        result = (str(log.event_timestamp),
            str(log.resource_group_name),
            log.event_name.localized_value,
            log.operation_name.localized_value)
        f.writerow(result)
```

When the `csv.writer` is added after opening the csv file it will work without TextIOwrapper error

Comment: please add the headers before the for loop starts

Comment: some how i am getting , comm after each letter from your code , the solution provided Daweo giving me expected result, but there also i have added headers before for loop, but it does not printing headers, i have used `headers = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4']`

Comment: please add ```f.writerow(headers)``` followed by above headers list

Comment: its works now :) thank you..  actually stack overflow should allow me to answer multiple answers as accepted where different ppl are helping me , hope they will bring this feature soon :)

Comment: ya thats a good idea .You're welcome .please do upvote for the answer